# Android fill tab layout with mysql json data

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-tablayout

I have spent so many days searching, but couldn't find a helpful tutorial on how to fill tab layout with MYSQL JSON data.

There is so many tutorials available for tab layout but nothing for MYSQL JSON in particular.

Can anyone help me on this please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Fill Tab layout with MYSQL JSON data.`? Thats a Vague question . Breakthe question in parts and then search .

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).